# Google maps v3 geocode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am trying to geocode an place name, however when I run the function, I get,

"an empty string" in my console,

below is my code why would this be happening?

```
function getLatLong(address) 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var result = "";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            result = results[0].geometry.location;
        } else {
            result = "Unable to find address: " + status;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I have got my value going to the console, now when I try and push the value of element into the function, I get undefined as a return, below is the full code,

```
function getLatLong(address) 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var result = "";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            result = results[0].geometry.location;
            return result;
        } else {
            result = "Unable to find address: " + status;
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}

//getLatLong("YORK"); 

function loadScript(postcode){
    alert(postcode);
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize?"+postcode;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
   }

   /* load map on visitors location */
   function initialize(postcode){
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(getLatLong(postcode));
     var myOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom:13,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
     map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng, 
      map: map,
      icon:'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/home.png',
     });
    }
```

And it is called like this,

```
 $(function(){
    $("dd a, dt a").live("click", function(){
        var self = $(this);
        $("#overlay").fadeIn('slow');
        var targetProcent = 85;
        var targetWidth = $(window).width() * (targetProcent / 100);
        var targetHeight = $(window).height() * (targetProcent / 100);   
        var targetX = ($(window).width() - targetWidth) / 2;
        var targetY = ($(window).height() - targetHeight) / 2 + $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#lightbox').height(700);
        $('#lightbox').width(targetWidth);
        $('#lightbox').load(self.attr("href"));
        loadScript($("#postcode").val());
        //usePointFromPostcode(document.getElementById('postcode').value, placeMarkerAtPoint)
        $('#lightbox').css({
            "position": "absolute", 
            "top": targetY+"px", 
            "left": targetX+"px"
        }).fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    });
```

$("#postcode").val() relates to an element that is loaded in when using load()

Answer (score 4):

you make an async call, and then print to console. the call hasnt returned yet

solution:

move the console.log into the callback

**edit:**
the callback is the anonymous function that you pass as an argument to geocode, its signature is `function(results, status)` you should put your `console.log` call at the END of that function

**EDIT for your edit:**

your script url looks like its wrong:

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize?"+postcode
```

i am pretty sure that tacking on ?postcode doesnt do anything. If anything, the url should only contain one ? before the start of the query params.
It seems like you want to pass the postcode to the `initialize` function, the easiest way to do that would be via a global variable.

set the global variable in the `loadScript` function and read it in the `initialize` function

Comment: change `});    console.log(result);` to 
`console.log(result); });`